# Panel won't dispose after opening another panel in java program

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a pharmacy management system in java and I've made a signup up panel using window builder.In that window builder there is a text saying click here to login.When I click the text,it opens up the login panel but doesn't dispose the signup panel. I just wanted someone who can show me how to dispose the signup panel when I click the login panel. Here's the code that I have written.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
public class SignUp extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;

int xx;
int xy;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SignUp frame = new SignUp();
                frame.setUndecorated(false);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setLocation(200, 10);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }

     public SignUp() {
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getXOnScreen();
            SignUp.this.setLocation(x-xx, y-xy);

        }
    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            xx=e.getX();
            xy=e.getY();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            SignUp frame = new SignUp();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 700);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    //contentPane.setUndecorated(true)
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 389, 681);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(57, 182, 256, 256);
    panel.add(lblNewLabel_3);


     JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("Login by clicking here");
     lblNewLabel_4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Login log = new Login();
            log.setResizable(false);
            log.show();
            log.setLocation(200, 10);
            log.setVisible(true);

            dispose();  
        }
        });


    lblNewLabel_4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblNewLabel_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 17));
    lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(85, 604, 192, 20);
    panel.add(lblNewLabel_4);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Sign Up");
    btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnNewButton.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(519, 608, 436, 34);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    //Main_Page frame = new Main_Page();

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(519, 150, 426, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
    lblUsername.setBounds(519, 130, 60, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(519, 250, 426, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
    lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
    lblEmail.setBounds(519, 230, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(519, 350, 426, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(519, 330, 60, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(519, 450, 426, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Confirm Password");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(519, 430, 101, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(583, 28, 284, 74);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) `SignUp frame = new SignUp();
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();` Those 3 lines of code are a heaping helping of pointless. It is likely you intended to set an existing, visible frame to be not visible, but that's not the frame that `frame` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a *new* `SignUp`, setting it non-visible, and disposing it.  That's useless, because the you want to hide (and maybe dispose) the *existing*, visible `SignUp`.  Instead of creating a new one, you need to invoke the appropriate methods on the existing one.  You might be able to reach that through the `MouseEvent`'s source, but otherwise you need to arrange for some other way for the listener to obtain it.

**Update**

A fuller code now having been presented in the question, it is clear that the `MouseListener` involved is an inner class of `SignUp`.  Supposing that the `SignUp` instance it is intended to dispose is always its own outer instance, it can just invoke methods on that instance (seemingly) directly.  That falls into the category of "some other way for the listener to obtain it."

Comment: Just had to write dispose(); at the end of mouse listener event. Let me update my question.

Comment: Yes, @BENJA, that makes sense in light of the code now presented in the question.  I have updated this answer to make the connection.